# Проксирование запроса NGINX в зависимости от того откуда пришел запрос

Tags: nginx, proxy

Доброго дня всем!

Подскажите пожалуйста, что-то не видно очевидного решения.
Возможно ли в NGINX проксировать пришедший запрос в зависимости от
того откуда этот запрос пришёл (`$http_referer`)?

Другими словами допустим пришел запрос на `test-domain.com`, c
`domain10.com` то проксироваться запрос должен на `172.20.20.10`. Если
пришёл с `domain11.com` то проксируется на `172.20.20.11`. Вот такая
зависимость.

Возможно ли парсить из url реферера цифру средствами NGINX чтобы потом
её подставить в ip адрес? Или придётся вызывать какой-то внешний
скрипт который всё это будет обрабатывать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
location / {
        if ($http_referer ~* "domain(\d{1,2}).com") {
          proxy_pass http://172.20.20.$1/;
        }
}
```

---

Дополнение в виду уточнения в комментарии.

Попробуйте задать соответствие при помощи директивы [map](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), таким образом:

```
map $http_referer $proxy_address {
   domain10.com 172.20.20.10;
   domain11.com 172.20.20.11;
   domain12.com 172.20.20.57;
}
```

Если значений много - то напишите вместо этих строчек `include <путь_к_файлу_со_значениями>` и укажите сопоставления в отдельном файле.
А уже в директиве proxy_pass пишите так - `proxy_pass http://$proxy_address;`

Comment: Отлично, а где можно почитать про то что регулярные выражения могут матчить переменные вот так как вы приводите в примере. Я что-то не встречал этого хотя искал.

Comment: Хотя, хотя... Оказывается всё несколько сложнее. Нужна отдельная таблица которая будет хранить сопоставление номеров в домене и ip адресов на которые проксировать. Так как эти цифры не совпадают. Как тут быть? На каждый запрос вызывать скрипт который будет возвращаться совпадающее значение?

Comment: Nginx использует PCRE (perl compatible regular extensions - совместимые с Perl регулярные выражения), так что можете почитать на эту тему в Сети. Мне эта статья нравится - http://citforum.ru/internet/perl/regexp/. А если хотите просто примеров вкратце, то вот здесь они есть - http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

Comment: Ок спасибо. А как быть с таблицей сопоставления номеров в именах доменов и реальными ip адресами, не подскажите?

Comment: @MishaPolitaev, обновил ответ.

Comment: Отлично! Выглядит как план! Отпишу по результатам)